# SQLite query throws a syntax error in code but works fine when copied into sqlite db browser

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

**Solution:** I had an out of date version of sqlite installed which didn't support RANK(). I fixed this by installing Python3.7.4

I am trying to find the position of a user when they are sorted in descending order based on the sum of two columns. I tested this query in SQLite DB Browser and it returned the correct result, but when I copied it into my Python script it throws a syntax error at one of the "("

I have tried running the code and stopping it just before it executes the query so that I can copy the query verbatim into the db browser. When I do that it works perfectly, but when I execute the query in my script it fails

Here is the plain text query that the string concatenation returns:

```sql
SELECT top_rank FROM (
    SELECT username, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY summed DESC) AS 'top_rank' 
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(positive_qc) - SUM(negative_qc) AS 'summed', username 
        FROM sub_activity 
        WHERE sub_name IN('cryptocurrency', 'cryptomarkets', 'cryptotechnology', 'blockchain') 
    GROUP BY username)
) WHERE username = 'someuser'
```

Here is the code I use to get that query:

```py
select_str = "SELECT top_rank FROM(" + \
                    "SELECT " + self.KEY2_USERNAME + ", RANK() OVER(ORDER BY summed DESC) AS 'top_rank' " \
                    "FROM(" \
                        "SELECT SUM(" + self.KEY2_POSITIVE_QC + ") - SUM(" + self.KEY2_NEGATIVE_QC + ") " \
                        "AS 'summed', " + self.KEY2_USERNAME + " " \
                        "FROM " + self.TABLE_SUB_ACTIVITY + " " \
                        "WHERE " + self.KEY2_SUB_NAME + " IN('" + "', '".join(sub_list) + "') " \
                    "GROUP BY " + self.KEY2_USERNAME + ")" \
             ") WHERE " + self.KEY2_USERNAME + " = ?"
```

The exact error I get when executing it in the script is

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

**Update:** I have narrowed down the error to the RANK () OVER(ORDER BY summed DESC) portion of the query

Comment: Have you tried putting a space `"SELECT top_rank FROM(" + \ ` between the `FROM` and the `(`?

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I just tried that and got the same result. I even added spaces between all the opening and closing parentheses and the error didn't change. Here's what the query looks like now:


```sql
SELECT top_rank FROM ( 
    SELECT username, RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY summed DESC ) AS top_rank 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT SUM ( positive_qc ) - SUM ( negative_qc ) AS summed, username 
        FROM sub_activity 
        WHERE sub_name IN ( 'cryptocurrency', 'cryptomarkets', 'cryptotechnology', 'blockchain'' ) 
    GROUP BY username ) 
) WHERE username = ?
```

Comment: In the post, `WHERE sub_name IN('cryptocurrency'` this would look like it's the issue. Between the `IN` and the `(`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA I just tried to execute the query with spaces before and after each ( and ) and it still had the same error

Comment: Try alias each subquery. I think that's your problem. I think it's confused on what the outer columns belong to what query.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Not sure what you mean by that. Are you talking about the username?

Comment: I posted as an answer... I got the same error until I aliased the subqueries.

Comment: Is your version of SQLite at least 3.25.0 to use window functions?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try... I aliased each subquery. `ui` and `uo`.

```
SELECT top_rank FROM (
    SELECT username, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY summed DESC) AS 'top_rank' 
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(positive_qc) - SUM(negative_qc) AS 'summed', username 
        FROM sub_activity 
        WHERE sub_name IN ('cryptocurrency', 'cryptomarkets', 'cryptotechnology', 'blockchain') 
    GROUP BY username) ui
) uo WHERE username = 'someuser'
```

Comment: I just tried that and I still get the same error. I think the issue is something with the RANK() OVER() part of the query. When I remove everything but that it still throws an error

Comment: Then I would look at the version as @forpas suggests.

Comment: You were right about the version number! I just updated to Python 3.7.8 and it's working like a charm. If I could kiss you I would

Comment: @JamesGrusheski  You should thank forpas on the original question.  forpas was the one who suggested checking the version.